# How to add space between the end of my text and the button?

Tags: css, html

This is a visual example of what I want to do

[image: Example]

Below is a snippet showing my CSS and HTML.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 1.5;
}
h1 {
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 1;
}
/* Start */

html {
  /*background-image:url('../images/stuff.jpg');
     background-attachment:fixed;
     background-position:center;
     background-repeat:no-repeat;*/
  background: url('http://placehold.it/1980x1020') fixed center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -mozilla-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
.orange {
  color: #f44d26;
}
.button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 24px;
  padding: 15px 65px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.button:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
/*0 (r), 0(g), 0(b), 0.3 (transparency up to 1) */

#container {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 1024px;
}
#info {
  width: 724px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/assets/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png" />

<div id="container">
  <div>
    <!-- add info ID -->
    <div id="info">
      <div>
        <header>
          <!-- Add span orange class -->
          <h1> Things and Stuff for <span class="orange">Designers.</span></h1>
        </header>

        <main>
          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <p>It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
            desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
            It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
            with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

          <div>
            <!-- Add button class -->
            <a href="#" class="button"> Learn More </a>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
      <!-- end of info ID-->
    </div>
    <!-- end of container ID-->
```

This is not gradable – it is simply for us to do to learn, but I've tried margin-top/bottom (depending on what I tried), etc. I'm not really sure what it could be and `<br>` of course is not what I want. I want to put it down roughly 2 lines.

Comment: "put it down". you mean the "learn more" button?

Comment: I'm sorry yes I do mean just the learn more button!

Comment: What's this have to do with SQL server?

Comment: My tags are html, css, and html5? Oh I'm so sorry it must've left it in from a post I never posted last time for SQL!

Comment: Your title say SQL Server: How to add space between the end of my text and the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick and dirty....

```
<br />
<br />
<br />
<a href="#" class="button"> Learn More </a>
```

Edit: Without br

```
<div id="buttonContainer">    
    <a href="#" class="button"> Learn More </a>
</div>
```

Add to CSS:

```
#buttonContainer{
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Without using <br>'s

Comment: I tried putting it in my CSS but it didn't change anything?

Comment: I've attempted to add it to .button and I attempted #buttonContainer but neither worked but the inline did any idea why? Sorry for making this more complicated than it should be.

Comment: Did you also give your div an id of buttonContainer as I did in my example?

Comment: The browser probably used a cached version of your stylesheet file. Reloading the page several times usually works.

Answer (score 0):

```
.button {
    background:transparent;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    border-radius:40px;
    color:#fff;
    font-size:24px;
    padding:15px 65px;
    text-decoration:none;
    /*add these lines to your button class*/
   display:block;
   margin-top:20px; /*use any number you want*/
}
```